# Using numpy with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy, pydev

Although I've been doing things with python by myself for a while now, I'm completely new to using python with external libraries. As a result, I seem to be having trouble getting numpy to work with PyDev.

Right now I'm using PyDev in Eclipse, so I first tried to go to *My Project* **>** Properties **>** PyDev - PYTHONPATH **>** External  Libraries **>** Add zip/jar/egg, similar to how I would add libraries in Eclipse. I then selected the numpy-1.9.0.zip file that I had downloaded. I tried importing numpy and using it, but I got the following error message in Eclipse:

> Undefined variable from import: array.

I looked this up, and tried a few different things. I tried going into Window **>** Preferences **>** PyDev **>** Interpreters **>** Python Interpreters. I selected Python 3.4.0, then went to Forced Builtins **>** New, and entered "numpy". This had no effect, so I tried going back to Window **>** Preferences **>** PyDev **>** Interpreters **>** Python Interpreters, selecting Python 3.4.0, and then, under Libraries, choosing New Egg/Zip(s), then adding the numpy-1.9.0.zip file. This had no effect. I also tried the String Substitution Variables tab under Window **>** Preferences **>** PyDev **>** Interpreters **>** Python Interpreters (Python 3.4.0). This did nothing.

Finally, I tried simply adding `# @UndefinedVariable` to the broken lines. When I ran it, it gave me the following error:

> `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`

What can I try to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to either use the setup.py from the downloaded archive or to download the "superpack"-executable for windows, if you work on windows anyway.

In PyDev, i overcame problems with new libraries by using the autoconfig button. If that doesn't work, another solution could be deleting and reconfiguring the python interpreter.